# New virtual environment deployment. Best practises

Tags: virtualization

Gentlemen, I'm setting a brand new virtual environment and I need some advice. Budget is extremely tight so I am planning to use WS 2016 Core, free StarWind for storage, Veeam Free for backups. It's my first time configuring a virtual enviornment, so the suggestions on components came from spiceworks:D Any advice and best practises are most welcome.

Comment: If this is a business critical server, best advice is to hire a professional to help you out. Most of the times you will get a system that will have many problems with your starting knowledge.

Comment: Correct! https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-pro-active-support <= similar to SimpliVity|HPE OmniWatch, Nimble|HPE InfoSight, and Nutanix Heartbeat (?).

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I've reached out to the StarWind guys and they are actually helping me set everything up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows Server Core is paid version of Windows, it just has no GUI... What you most probably want is called free Hyper-V Server.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/hyper-v-server-2016

StarWind / Veeam guys work just fine, people run hundreds of nodes configured this way.